# Want to write to a file converting an integer list of Hex to Char

Tags: c#, .net, ascii

So I have a list full of integers.  These integers are hexadecimals.  I would like to convert this list to ASCII Chars.  Once that is done I would like to write the ASCII chars to a file.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    public byte[] buffer;
    public List<int> list= new List<int>(new int[3]);
    list[0] = 5445535420;        //AKA header[0] represents the hex integers for Test_  where _ is a space
    list[1] = 0;                 // so the char would be null
    list[2] = 4a4153;            // would be JAS


    System.IO.FileStream fs;
    fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    if (fs.CanWrite)
    {
         for (int i=0;i<list.Count();i++)
         {
              buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(list[i].ToString());
              Convert.ToChar(header[i]);
              fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         }             
     }
```

Comment: Looks like the hex values represent strings, not just chars. One more thing, `5445535420` is not a valid _int_ value and `4a4153` is not a valid representation of a _hex_ value. `0x4a4153` is. This code won't even compile.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed yes you are correct the hex values represent strings.  From my understanding the conversion is done  for each char in a string.  Why is 5445535420 not a valid int value? I do not understand how a number could be an invalid int.  If the hex value is 0x4a4153 , how would I express that as an int to declare it equal to list[2]? Yes this does compile with it only writing the list to my file and not the conversition to char.  I understand this will happen as I have fs.write(buffer).  I would like to understand how to get the correct scenario where I am able to do fs.write(char)

Comment: The `int` data type is a signed 32-bit data type. I leave it to you to figure out how many bits you would need to represent 5445535420 (bonus task: try to figure out the same for the hex number 0x5445535420)... ;-)

Comment: Also, what is the point of `new List<int>(new int[3]);`? (Check the documentation of the List<T> constructor, if you want to know what that really does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) If you just want to set the initial capacity of the list, use `new List<int>(3);` (although this is not really necessary here in your case). Note that "initial capacity" is not the same as the size/length/count of the list. You can still add as many ints to the list as you like...

Comment: In `list[1] = 0`, how do you tell if it has one character ("\0") or 4 ("\0\0\0\0")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? Hope comments are self-explenatory

```
    int intFromHexLiteral = 0x4a4153;
    var hexString = intFromHexLiteral.ToString("X"); // "4A4153"
    var hexCharsList = Split(hexString, 2).ToList(); // ["4A", "41", "53"]
    var charsArray = hexCharsList
        .Select(hexChar => Convert.ToInt32(hexChar, 16)) // [74, 65, 83]
        .Select(i => (char) i) // ['J', 'A', 'S']
        .ToArray();
    var word = new string(charsArray); // "JAS"

    private static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize) =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
            .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer does not equal the bytes of the ASCII characters. I.e 1010 is not 0x1010 in hex. In your case it would make more sense to use byte[] an write each hex character explicitly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>();
        list.Add(new byte[]{0x54, 0x45, 0x53, 0x54, 0x20}); //AKA header[0] represents the hex integers for Test_  where _ is a space
        list.Add(new byte[]{0x0});                          // so the char would be null
        list.Add(new byte[]{ 0x4a, 0x41, 0x53 });           // would be JAS

        foreach (var b in list)
        {
            var chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(b);
            var s = new string(chars);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  In your answer you have converted to chars which is fantastic.  I am just wondering how I would write these converted chars to the file using fs.write.  If fs.write is not the best method please let me know if another is better

Comment: File.WriteAllText (string path, string content)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've selected an answer, but I wanted to show you this method of solving your problem dealing with your data strictly as numeric data.  The values you stick into your `List<int>` are small enough to fit into a `long` so I changed it to a `List<long>`.  If they ever become bigger than that, than this solution would not work.

See how I broke each `long` element, byte by byte, in reverse and stored the conversion into a `StringBuilder` before writing it to the screen.  In your case, you would write to a file instead, but could use the same conversion method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<long> list = new List<long>(new long[3]);
        list[0] = 0x5445535420;         // AKA header[0] represents the hex integers for Test_  where _ is a space
        list[1] = 0;                    // so the char would be null
        list[2] = 0x4a4153;             // would be JAS

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Break down each element byte by byte in reverse
            while (list[i] > 0)
            {
                // Anding against 0xFF to only have the least significant byte to convert into a char
                sb.Insert(0, Convert.ToChar(list[i] & 0xFF));
                list[i] >>= 8;  // Remove the least significant byte
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
TEST

JAS
```